# Flutter: widget has been unmounted issue during dismissible actions

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i have an issue with the widget unmounted with dismissdirection action on flutter. When I left swipe the dismissible item with the deleted action confirmed, the error occured as following:

> The following assertion was thrown while notifying status listeners for AnimationController:
> This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered
> defunct).
> Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if
> the State is still active.

The full error codes are [here](http://txt.do/tsczh)

My code:
home_page.dart. The homepage I use statefulwidget and redirect to **ExpensesCategoryHistory()** Screen.

```
     class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      const HomePage({Key key, this.database, this.budget}) : super(key: key);
      final DatabaseService database;
      final Budget budget;
    
      @override
      _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
    }
    
    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final database = Provider.of<DatabaseService>(context, listen: false);
        PersistentTabController _controller;
    
        _controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);
    
        return PersistentTabView(
          context,
          controller: _controller,
          screens: _buildScreens(),
          items: _navBarsItems(),
          confineInSafeArea: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          stateManagement: true,
          hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true, // Recommended to set 'resizeToAvoidBottomInset' as true while using this argument. Default is true.
          decoration: NavBarDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            colorBehindNavBar: Colors.white,
          ),
          popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
          popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,
          itemAnimationProperties: ItemAnimationProperties( // Navigation Bar's items animation properties.
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            curve: Curves.ease,
          ),
          screenTransitionAnimation: ScreenTransitionAnimation( // Screen transition animation on change of selected tab.
            animateTabTransition: true,
            curve: Curves.ease,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
          ),
          navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style15, // Choose the nav bar style with this property.
        );
      }
    }

List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
  return [
    Home(),
    ExpensesCategoryHistory(),
    BudgetPage(),
    Container(),
    Container()
  ];
}
```

Then, in the **ExpensesCategoryHistory()** class. So, user can select the category and prompt expenses based on the category (when the list item is tapped.) **Refer Steps 4 of error occured with images**

```
class ExpensesCategoryHistory extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExpensesCategoryHistoryState createState() => _ExpensesCategoryHistoryState();
}

class _ExpensesCategoryHistoryState extends State<ExpensesCategoryHistory> {

  var categoryList = ["Beauty", "Entertainment", "Food & Drinks", "Groceries", "Medical", "Transport", "Others"]; 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
        title: Text('Expenses History By Category'),
      ),
      body: _buildContents(context),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () => EditExpensesPage.show(context,
          database: Provider.of<DatabaseService>(context, listen: false),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContents(BuildContext context) {
    final database = Provider.of<DatabaseService>(context, listen: false);

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: categoryList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
        return ListTile(
          title: Text('${categoryList[index]}'),
          onTap: () {
            if(mounted){
              Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute<Widget>(
                  builder: (context) => ExpensesHistory(Category: categoryList[index]),
                  ),
            );
            }
          },
        );
      },
    );
    
  }
}
```

Then, lasty the main issue is here. When user select on delete action after left swipe of item. The error code occurred and did not perform `Navigator.of(context).pop(true)`
**ExpensesHistory** class

```
    class ExpensesHistory extends StatelessWidget {
   // Declare a field that holds the Todo.
  final String Category;

  // In the constructor, require a Todo.
  ExpensesHistory({Key key, @required this.Category}) : super(key: key);

  Future<void> _delete(BuildContext context, Expense expense) async {
    try {
      final database = Provider.of<DatabaseService>(context, listen: false);
      await database.deleteExpenses(expense);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) { //handle error
      PlatformExceptionAlertDialog(
        title: 'Operation failed',
        exception: e,
      ).show(context);
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
        title: Text('$Category'),
      ),
      body: _buildContents(context),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () => EditExpensesPage.show(context,
          database: Provider.of<DatabaseService>(context, listen: false),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContents(BuildContext context) {
    final database = Provider.of<DatabaseService>(context, listen: false);
    List myExpenses = [];

    return StreamBuilder<List<Expense>>(
      stream: database.expensesStream(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return ListItemsBuilder<Expense>(
          snapshot: snapshot,
          itemBuilder: (context, expense) =>
              Dismissible(
                confirmDismiss: (DismissDirection direction) async {
                  return await showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        title: const Text("Delete Confirmation"),
                        content: const Text(
                            "Are you sure you want to delete this item?"),
                        actions: <Widget>[
                          FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                            child: const Text("Delete"),
                          ),
                          FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                            child: const Text("Cancel"),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
                key: UniqueKey(),
                background: slideRightBackground(),
                direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                onDismissed: (direction) => _delete(context, expense),
                child: ExpensesListTile(
                  expense: expense,
                  onTap: () => ExpensesCategoryPage.show(context, expense),
                  category: Category,
                ),
              ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**Steps of error occured with images**

1. To ExpensesCategoryHistory class, render page [here](https://ibb.co/CtG4wXj)
2. Select category Beauty [here](https://ibb.co/V2YCLpX)
3. Render Beauty category item [here](https://ibb.co/tb1PzBz)
4. Confirm Delete action on category item after left swipe of dismissible [here](https://ibb.co/5kyv8sk)
5. Selected delete, prompt error code + item not deleted
6. Return **stay step 3**

Sorry for the full codes, but I wonder if my implementation issue on flutter/dart? I have been solving for days but still same issue, even I've read couple related issues on stackoverflow. Any help is greatly appreciated !

**Tested**

1. All widgets are mounted within 3 classes after routing.
2. Error occurred when deleted action is tapped but widget is mounted still.